# Tableau : set as a context filter, order of operations?

Tags: filter, set, tableau-api, operator-precedence, tableau-desktop

What it the **order of operation** when you place a **set** in the filter shelf and promote it as a **context filter** ? Is my  set context filter applied before any fixed LOD calculations for instance ?

According to the official documentation set filters [ref](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/order_of_operations.htm) are normally computed just after context filters . But know that my set is a context filter I end up very confused.

Best Alexis

Answer (score 0):

According to this post [Nick Jastrzebski](https://www.theinformationlab.co.uk/2019/09/02/removing-values-from-quick-filters-using-tableaus-order-of-operations/):
"The useful thing here is that set filters can also be added to context, so if you already have dimension filters in context, you can still modify the values these display by creating a set and adding that to context – **the order of operations for these are nested**:

[image: Context filter nesting]

This can give you a lot of freedom in filtering values in a certain order. When you also consider this can also apply to fixed level of detail calculations or top N filters, you have may options for how to slice & dice your data to display exactly what you want, especially if you already have a complex set of filters applied to your sheet."